# Proof of joint Gaussian distribution in a linear equation

Tags: gaussian

Let $X = AY + Z$ where $A$ is constant, $Y$ and $Z$ are independent gaussian rvs. How do you prove that $X$ and $Y$ are jointly gaussian? I know that the sum of two independent gaussians gives a gaussian distribution. But I have no idea where to start to show joint gaussian pdf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every linear combination of $X$ and $Y$ :
$$ \mu X + \beta Y = (\beta + \mu A) Y + \mu A Z$$
And since $Y$ and $Z$ are independent, the linear combination follows a gaussian distribution. So they are jointly gaussian.

Comment: How does linear combination of two gaussians imply the joint gaussianity?

Comment: By definition. $X$ and $Y$ are jointly gaussian if every linear combinations are gaussian.

Comment: Can you give me a reference about this?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Equivalent_definitions   Moreover, the equivalence is straighforward : think about the characteristic function